# Searching Apps in App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to search Apps in App Store by a keyword. Lets say if i type in "poker" and press enter then,

it should open all the apps in App Store having the string "poker" in there name or in description. i looked for Search API of apple but i am not able to find the specific term to search apps in App Store instead of itunes there. Examples out [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) are also only for itunes not for the apps in App Store.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the AppStore is a part of iTunes.

if you use `&entity=software` in the search API, you'll be searching the AppStore.

a search for the example you proposed: http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=poker&entity=software

Comment: thanks alot. Read whole document but skipped this. :P thanks again for the help.